# Major contributors to a Wikipedia article

Tags: wikipedia

The history of a Wikipedia article contains many contributors, most of them are minor (e.g. typo correction or adding a link). Usually there are 1-3 major contributors. Is there an automatic way to get a list of major contributors to a Wikipedia page?

(I mean something similar to the feature in a SE wiki answer, that shows the percentage of contribution of the major contributors.)

Comment: AFAIK, there is nothing like that directly in Wikipedia. There might be a third-party tool that does this.

Comment: There's https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:List_of_Wikipedians_by_number_of_edits

Comment: @MartinSchröder these are global counts, while I asked for counts per article. Additionally, these are raw numbers of edits, while I asked for major edits (e.g. one major edit should count more than 100 tiny edits).

Comment: If you are going to trust that page editors always set 'minor edit' flag correctly, your results will be skewed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is - the [Page History Tool](https://xtools.wmflabs.org/articleinfo) on [Wikimedia Xtools](https://xtools.wmflabs.org/).

[Here's an example](https://xtools.wmflabs.org/articleinfo/en.wikipedia.org/Stack_Exchange#top-editors) of it showing the users who've contributed the highest number of edits to the [Stack Exchange article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_exchange). Unfortunately, it counts the raw number of edits, not the percentage of contribution as you've requested, although it does distinguish between major and minor edits (in brackets after the number of edits).

It's linked from each article's [page information](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Stack_Exchange&action=info) section, available in Wikipedia's left-hand navigation.